# How to search a specific link on google results using Delphi WebBrowser Component

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am using webrowser component on Delphi. I have 2 edit box. I am entering a keyword to the first one and I am entering a website name to the second one. When I hit Search it is displaying the google results. I want the to search the website name (which I enter to the 2nd editbox)  on the displayed results and want it to be automatically clicked. But I don't have any clue how to do that. Can you please advise me?
Thank you.

Comment: Well, there's not much to help with. Inspect the document and click on links of your interest. How to click on link with web browser control you'll surely find somewhere. Found links on the first site seems to be placed at XPath `//*[@id="rso"]/div/li[1]/div/h3/a` where `1` is the index of the `li` element. In all cases, you are violating Google rules.

Comment: You have to use the browser's DOM interfaces to retrieve the HTML, then you can parse it as needed, and then use the DOM again to click on the desired link or navigate the browser to the desired URL. Examples of using browser DOMs are readily available if you search around.

Comment: Thanky you Remy and TLama. I searched as a "delphi browser doms" on google but results weren't clear enough. Can you please provide me a link of example. Cheers.

Comment: HTML DOM has nothing to do with Delphi. It's HTML. Search on "HTML DOM Model" (without the "Delphi"). (Of course, the easiest way to accomplish this is to limit the search *before it happens* by using the "site" parameter in the URL, instead of trying to search the generic results for a specific site. If you use "site", any and all results you get will be from that site. (Try a Google search in your web browser, and look at the URL in the browser's location bar when it displays the first page of results, and look for "site%3" in that URL to see how it's done.)

Comment: thanks will try. shame that its paid.